# zip extract all fail for the "_" iconic zip c#

Tags: c#, unzip

I am trying to unzip a folder which contains filename or foldername as"folder_name".

```
try{
    zip.extractall(path);
    }
catch(Exception ex){
    log.info(ex.message);
    }
```

if foldername contain underscore, its throwing below exception:

> "The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully
>   qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the
>   directory name must be less than 248 characters"

i am using iconic zip dll for unzipping. Is there any solution to rectify this issue.

Comment: The error you quote suggests that the underscores are not the cause, can you verify that?

Comment: if i am removing underscore, its working fine @UlrichEckhardt

Comment: Not sure why the path is a problem, however you could always extract to a temporary location and copy when finished

Comment: Also if you are using DotNetZip, there is discussions in the the original codeplex project about people having issues with underscores. maybe just use a different library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is limitation of Microsoft that we can not add more than 260 chars. This issue has fixed in windows 10.

In my case, I removed the junk path from the location. Now, It is working fine.